# How would I find the mode (stats) of pixel values of an image?

Tags: opencv, numpy, scipy

I'm using opencv and I'm able to get a pixel of an image-- a 3-dimensional tuple, via the code below. However, I'm not quite sure how to calculate the mode of the pixels values in the image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
import cv2


img =cv2.imread('C:\\Users\Moondra\ABEO.png')

#px = img[100,100]  #gets pixel value
#print (px)
```

I tried,

```
from scipy import stats
stats.mode(img)[0]
```

But this returns an array shape of

```
stats.mode(img)[0].shape
(1, 800, 3)
```

Not sure how exactly `stats` is calculating the dimensions from which to choose the mode, but I'm looking for each pixel value (3 dimensional tuple) to be one element.

EDIT:
For clarity, I'm going to lay out exactly what I'm looking for.
Let's say we have an array that is of shape (3,5,3) and looks like this

```
array([[[1, 1, 2],    #[1,1,2] = represents the RGB values
        [2, 2, 2],
        [1, 2, 2],
        [2, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 2]],

       [[1, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [1, 2, 2],
        [1, 2, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 1],
        [2, 2, 1],
        [1, 1, 2],
        [2, 1, 2],
        [1, 1, 2]]])
```

I would then convert it to an array that looks like this for easier calculation

Turn this into

```
array([[1, 1, 2],
         [2, 2, 2],
         [1, 2, 2],
        [2, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 2],

       [1, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [1, 2, 2],
        [1, 2, 1],

       [2, 2, 1],
        [2, 2, 1],
        [1, 1, 2],
        [2, 1, 2],
        [1, 1, 2]])


which is of shape(15,3)
```

I would like to calculate the mode by counting each set of RGB as follows:

```
 [1,1,2] = 3
 [2,2,2] = 4  
[1,2,2] = 4
[2,1,1] = 2
[1,1,2] =1
```

Thank you.

Comment: `stats.mode(img, axis=-1)[0]`?

Comment: Going to test it out.

Comment: Quick test with `axis =0,1,2 and -1`, is still producing a large array. Going to retest.

Comment: stats.mode(img, axis= -1)[0].shape
`(400, 800, 1)`

Comment: What output shape are you expecting?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `(1, 1, 3)` if it's only 3 values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the description, it seems you are after the pixel that's occurring the most in the input image. To solve for the same, here's one efficient approach using the concept of `views` -

```
def get_row_view(a):
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * np.prod(a.shape[-1])))
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    return a.reshape(-1, a.shape[-1]).view(void_dt).ravel()

def get_mode(img):
    unq, idx, count = np.unique(get_row_view(img), return_index=1, return_counts=1)
    return img.reshape(-1,img.shape[-1])[idx[count.argmax()]]
```

We can also make use of `np.unique` with its `axis` argument, like so -

```
def get_mode(img):
    unq,count = np.unique(img.reshape(-1,img.shape[-1]), axis=0, return_counts=True)
    return unq[count.argmax()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [69]: img = np.random.randint(0,255,(4,5,3))

In [70]: img.reshape(-1,3)[np.random.choice(20,10,replace=0)] = 120

In [71]: img
Out[71]: 
array([[[120, 120, 120],
        [ 79, 105, 218],
        [ 16,  55, 239],
        [120, 120, 120],
        [239,  95, 209]],

       [[241,  18, 221],
        [202, 185, 142],
        [  7,  47, 161],
        [120, 120, 120],
        [120, 120, 120]],

       [[120, 120, 120],
        [ 62,  41, 157],
        [120, 120, 120],
        [120, 120, 120],
        [120, 120, 120]],

       [[120, 120, 120],
        [  0, 107,  34],
        [  9,  83, 183],
        [120, 120, 120],
        [ 43, 121, 154]]])

In [74]: get_mode(img)
Out[74]: array([120, 120, 120])
```

Comment: So it's calculating the mode value of each channel separately instead of together?  So it wouldn't be a true pixel value right?

Comment: @moondra How could you have mode computed all R, G, B channels together and end up with a (1,1,3) shaped output? I think you should mock up a sample `(4,5,3)` shaped image array and explain to us what exactly you are after.

Comment: Okay, will add. Give me second.

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic, but I'm curious as to how you able to direct a comment at me? i.e @moondra. Do you manually type in @USERNAME? Thank you.

Comment: @moondra Type "@" and then press "Spacebar, the usernames linked to the post would show up as a list and then you can select the one that you want to send msg to.

Comment: Thank you. Lot of concepts that are unfamiliar to me, so I'm going through the code line by line. '`void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * np.prod(a.shape[-1])))`  . From what I"m gathering, you assigned the dtype as void for faster calculations?  I'm having trouble understanding the next portion; `a.dtype.itemsize`  seems to be '1' if `img` = `a`. np.prod(a.shape[-1]) seems to equal 'a.shape[-1]`, so I don't understand why `np.prod` is used.  Is this entire line changing the dtype, to make it more computationally efficient?

Comment: @moondra Well, we are viewing each row as one scalar with that func `get_row_view`. Yes, the whole idea is efficiency here, because all we are doing is "viewing" without creating any more data or anymore heavy computations.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. After playing around with your code, your view function seems to have transformed each pixel value(rgb) into a unique vector in itself.  So when you run `np.unique` it's able to count each vector and find out which one is the most frequent. This code was way above my comprehension level, but I learned a lot. I think If I just follow you around, and read all of your answers, I will probably learn the most efficient numpy code.   =)  

Thank you so much.